# Batch: How to focus on cmd after task is initialized

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, focus

Say my program is as follows

```
@ECHO Off
 start "" "Notepad.exe"
 pause
```

After it opens notepad the windows focus is on notepad so whatever I type is on there, but I want the focus to go back to cmd; is this possible? How?

The specific program i'm trying to run it on, is below:

```
@ECHO OFF
title SortV8
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
cd "C:\img\Unsorted"
:SORT
FOR /R %%f IN (*.jpg *.png *.gif *.jpeg) DO (
 echo Current file is: %%f
 start "" "D:\Downloads\ImageGlass_Kobe_8.6.7.13_x64\ImageGlass.exe" %%f
 powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).AppActivate((Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter \"ProcessId = $PID\").ParentProcessId)"
 CHOICE /N /C 1234 /M "PICK A NUMBER (1 (Photo), 2 (Video), or 3(Delete), 4 (Terminate Program)"%1
 IF ERRORLEVEL 4 goto END
 IF ERRORLEVEL 3 echo "To the trash it goes!" && move %%f "C:\img\Delete"
 IF ERRORLEVEL 2 echo "Video" && move %%f "C:\img\Videos"
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 echo "Photo" &&  move %%f "C:\img\Photos"
 taskkill /IM ImageGlass.exe
 cls
 GOTO SORT
)

:END
taskkill /IM ImageGlass.exe
cls
echo "Goodbye!"
pause
:eol
```

Comment: Personally, I'd just use Irfanview which has this functionality as F7

Comment: How owuld I go about doing that?

Comment: Search for "Irfanview" using Google.

Comment: Huh ok you mean using another program; could work; I can still close the program qith Esc;; my idea would be no to need a key and just go directly towards the cmd

Answer (score 2):

You can use PowerShell via its [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) to reactivate your console window, but note that the execution overhead is not insignificant.

**Note**: This solution is **not fully robust**, but may work well enough in practice:

```bash
@ECHO Off

:: Asynchronously launch Notepad, which steals the focus
:: (Notepad becomes the active window).
start "" "Notepad.exe"

:: Reactivate this console window with the help of PowerShell.
powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).SendKeys('%%{tab}')"

pause
```

The above simulates user input, namely an <kbd>Alt-Tab</kbd> keypress, in order to reactivate the current console window.
This relies on:

- Notepad's window already having been activated (which is likely, given the execution overhead of calling `powershell.exe`)
- the user not manually activating other windows while the batch file runs.

---

The **following variant is more robust**, but has a **prerequisite that is unlikely to be met**:

- Rather than sending keystrokes, it properly tries to reactivate the current console window via its process ID.
- However, this **programmatic window activation only succeeds if the effective `SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT` value as reported by the [`SystemParametersInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfow) WinAPI function WinAPI function in the current OS uses session is `0`, which is *not* the case by default.**

  - While it is possible *in principle* to set this value to `0` on demand with PowerShell code, executing such code *from `cmd.exe` (a batch file*) inexplicably fails with an `Access denied` error (whereas direct execution of the same code works fine *from PowerShell*) - I haven't found a way around this (if someone has an explanation or solution, please tell us).
  - Certain third-party software - notably [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) - itself sets the value to `0` once it has run in a session, so if you happen to have a run-on-login AutoHotkey script (it doesn't matter what it does), the code below *will* work. That said, if you have AutoHotkey already installed, you could try to solve the problem at hand with a specific AutoHotkey script.

```bash
@ECHO Off

:: Asynchronously launch Notepad, which steals the focus
:: (Notepad becomes the active window).
start "" "Notepad.exe"

:: !! SEE LIMITATION DISCUSSED ABOVE
:: Reactivate this console window with the help of PowerShell.
powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "$null = (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).AppActivate((Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter \"ProcessId = $PID\").ParentProcessId)"

pause
```

Comment: @Remi, I found a solution that may be good enough - please see my update.